# no module named 'codecs' при запуске cx_Freeze-скомпилированной программы

Tags: python, cx-freeze

Здравствуйте.
Передо мной стала задача скомпилировать мой `main.py` в `main.exe`. Наткнулся в интернете на статью [Компиляция программы на python 3 в exe с помощью программы cx_Freeze](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/program-compilation-with-cx-freeze.html)

Скомпилировал, но после запуска получаю ошибку:

> Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: unable to load the file system
>   codec Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "D:\PY\lib\encodings__init__.py", line 31, in 
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'codecs'

Подскажите, что можно сделать, в интернете нет толкового исчерпывающего ответа. Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Файл находится в той же директории, где и компилился?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не получается создать exe файл из файла .py используя cx freeze на Python 3.6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/688662/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-exe-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-py-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-cx-freeze-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python-3-6)

Comment: @Twiss с codecs другой косяк обычно

Answer (score 1):

Предполагаю, что у Вас установлена версия cx_freeze доступная через pip. К сожалению, эта версия содержит странные ошибки, вроде этой с codecs.
Для устранения ошибки:

- удалите установленный `cx_freeze`,
- скачайте последнюю версию сборки модуля отсюда https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Freeze,
- установите cx_freeze из скачанного локального файла `pip install <имя_файла.whl>`

Comment: чтобы обновить пакет, обычно: `pip install -U <имя-пакета>` (pip самостоятельно удалит старую версия, установит новую).