# Не получается создать exe файл из файла .py используя cx freeze на Python 3.6

Tags: python, cx-freeze

Файл создается но при открытие вылетают ошибки и файл закрывается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пробовал через py2exe но файл даже не создался, может кто что подскажет

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
packages = ["vk","requests","json","urllib.request","os","time"]
build_exe_options = {
"packages": packages,
"includes": packages,
'include_files': [],
'zip_include_packages': "*",
'zip_exclude_packages': None,
'include_msvcr': True,
'constants':{}
}
setup(
  name = "reer",
  version = "0.1",
  description = "Blackjack",
  options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
  executables = [Executable("reer.py")]
)
```

Comment: Логи ошибок лучше прикреплять к вопросу текстом. По вопросу - есть свежая статья по теме: http://jenyay.net/Programming/Cxfreeze

Comment: https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/program-compilation-with-cx-freeze.html<br>
**Делайте по уроку и у вас все получится**<br>
*Во всяком случае у **меня** все получилось:)* > Один недостаток: запускается вместе с консолью

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добавь список пакетов в файле setup.py для cx_freeze.

```
packages = ["os","utils","struct","mschap","pytz","motor","aiohttp","asyncio","sms"]
```

Этот список положишь в параметры, например дальше у меня так:

```
build_exe_options = {
    "packages": packages,
    "excludes": excludes,
    "includes": packages,
    'include_files': [],
    'zip_include_packages': "*",
    'zip_exclude_packages': None,
    'include_msvcr': True,
    'constants':{}
}
```

и передаём в

```
cx_setup(  name = "project",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "project build",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = executables,
        data_files = ['config.json']
        )
```

В твоем случае пакет `inda` плохо собирается - надо добавить его.

Comment: Большое Спасибо