# Скомпилировать .py в .exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, cx-freeze

Как скомпилировать .exe для работы программы на любом компьютере? 
Есть скрипт test.py

```
    from open3d import *
    import numpy as np
    import copy
    import sys
    import os

    def draw_registration_result(source, target, transformation):
        source_temp = copy.deepcopy(source)
        target_temp = copy.deepcopy(target)
        source_temp.paint_uniform_color([1, 0.706, 0])
        target_temp.paint_uniform_color([0, 0.651, 0.929])
        source_temp.transform(transformation)
        #draw_geometries([source_temp, target_temp])
        test = source_temp + target_temp
        write_point_cloud('test_combined.xyz', test)
        print("Успешно")
...
```

Сделал скрипт setup.py как указано [тут](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrUbj.png) с указанием используемых пакетов

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import matplotlib
import os
PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.__file__))
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR,'tcl','tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'tcl', 'tk8.6')

files = {"include_files": ["D:/Python36/DLLs/tcl86t.dll", "D:/Python36/DLLs/tk86t.dll"], "packages": ["tkinter", "easygui","matplotlib"]}
packages = ["open3d", "numpy","sys","os","copy"]
build_exe_options = {
"packages": packages,
"includes": packages,
'include_files': [],
'zip_include_packages': "*",
'zip_exclude_packages': None,
'include_msvcr': True,
'constants':{}
}
setup(
  name = "test",
  version = "0.1",
  description = "Blackjack",
  options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
  executables = [Executable("test.py")]
)
```

Использовал cx_Freeze для создания .exe файла, команда `python setup.py build` отрабатывает успешно и создает исполняемый файл. При использовании программы такая ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Пробовал установить pyinstaller, но безуспешно, он никак не хочет устанавливаться на мою версию питона 3.6
Подскажите, как правильно сделать, чтобы программа заработала?

P.s. я новичок в программировании на Python

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не получается создать exe файл из файла .py используя cx freeze на Python 3.6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/688662/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-exe-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-py-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d1%8f-cx-freeze-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python-3-6)

Comment: @Эникейщик Я предполагаю, что у меня проблема с импортом "from open3d import * ", и я не знаю как явно указать ее, чтобы она тоже была включена